# Laptop fan works mechanically but is not activating in Windows

Tags: laptop, bios, fan, cooling

I have a Dell Inspiron that is just out of warranty (of course). It started shutting down to protect from overheating, which is when I noticed that the internal fan was no longer turning on.

I rebooted into Dell's diagnostics and ran tests, and everything came out good. I could hear the fan spin up as expected when running the fan test.

I installed Speedfan to get some more information, and I could manually control the fan through that, but running Prime95 just heated everything up and didn't automatically enable the fan as it should. All of the temps appeared to be reading just fine. At this point I suspect that there is some software issue that is either not reading the temps properly or just not telling the fan to turn on automatically.

I saw that there was a BIOS update through Dell, so I downloaded and installed that. The weird thing is that as soon as it started installing the new BIOS, the fan started blowing like normal. And then as soon as the install was complete, the fan stopped...

Any advice on what this problem could be?

**Edit**
Windows Power settings have the cooling set to "Active", so I don't believe that's the issue.

Comment: It's possible that the fan is set not to spin up to full speed. Check in the BIOS and in windows power settings for it.

Comment: Thanks - the Windows Power settings have the cooling set to "Active", and there is nothing in the BIOS that I can access that lets me update the fan settings.

Comment: How was the machine being used at the time? Were you on a soft or hard surface? Battery or mains?

Comment: Plugged in via AC at all times with battery. Mostly hard surface, but also propped up on the side so there is as little contact as possible.

Comment: You can find some advice [here](http://www.pcnexus.net/2014/02/laptop-internal-cooling-fan-not-working-tips-to-solve.html) that can get you started. Have a look also at the fan to see if it has warped or wobbles or is not well-seated, and a bit of oil on the shaft may help.

Comment: sounds like, you havent changed Heat sink for a long time, i'd suggest you to do so... and diassemble laptop ( anyway it doesn't have any warranty yet) and make a general cleanup. 
Also, havent you recently used some sort of overclocking programs like RivaTuner and etc? Because if you did, then changes of fan rotation speed can be controlled programmatically aswell too.

Comment: @Alec Sanger What are your temps ? (at idle and doing some basic tasks) (see HWMonitor)

Comment: idle is around 55C, temps get up to the high 80s while I'm stressing it, and would certainly go higher if I let it. Seems like they hang out around the mid-70s when doing simple tasks for a while.

Answer (score 0):

In Device Manager, do you have any 'unknown' devices?  Perhaps there is a Dell interface component which needs to be updated/installed again so Windows can communicate with the fan controller.